# Is there any counter observable through Rx?

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming

I am looking for something I would call `CounterObservable` One side would count the numbers on it and other side would be the observer side that will receive notification every time total count changes.

In other words I will have something like this

```
public CounterObservable totalMailsReceived = new CounterObservable(0);

public void OnNewMail(Mail mail) 
{
   totalMailsReceived++;
   ///Rest of the code goes here
}
```

on the Observer side I will have

```
mailManager.totalMailsReceived.Subscribe(count => labelCount.Text = count.ToString());
```

Or if I want to go real classy, I would use Paul Betts' ReactiveUI like the following

```
mailManager.totalMailsReceived.ToProperty(x => x.TotalMailsReceived);
```

I have so far found nothing in Rx that could help me. But I figured if I create my own class that implements `IObservable<int>`. I am thinking of leveraging the [Sample MSDN Code for IObservable implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for that.

My questions are
1. Is that [MSDN Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) thread-safe ?
2. Is there really nothing in Rx already that does what I am trying to do ?

Answer (score 4):

Just use a [BehaviorSubject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211949%28v=vs.103%29.aspx):

```
public class MailServer
{
    private BehaviorSubject<int> _count = new BehaviorSubject<int>(0);

    public IObservable<int> TotalMailsReceived
    {
        get { return _count; }
    }

    public void OnNewMail(Mail mail)
    {
        _count.OnNext(_count.Value + 1);
    }
}
```

Or, if you decide to go deeper into Rx, so that you are just observing a `Mail` stream, then you can use [Scan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.scan%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) operator which is good for that and [Publish](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211622%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) to remember the most recent value and multicast it to all subscribers.

You can write this new extension method:

```
public IObservable<T> RunningTotal<T>(this IObservable<T> source)
{
    return source.Scan(0, sum => sum + 1);
}
```

And use it like so:

```
public class MailServer
{
    private IConnectableObservable<int> _total;
    private IDisposable _subscription;

    public MailServer(IObservable<Mail> incomingMail)
    {
        _total = incomingMail.RunningTotal().Publish(0);
        _subscription = _total.Connect();
    }

    public IObservable<int> TotalMailsReceived
    {
        get { return _total; }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Select` has a counter too, so instead of the `Scan` you can do: `return source.Select((_,i) => i);` - not that it's particularly better, just sayin'!

Comment: Is `_count.OnNext(_count.Value + 1);` an atomic operation? Otherwise it can miss some increments under heavy load.

Comment: no.  That's why its better to just make your trigger an observable stream that you just chain via Select or Scan.